# How to use custom css with bootstrap css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use custom css with twitter bootstrap for features like popover and modal dialogs. But because of the bootstrap css the site has an improper alignment. I tried using a reset css but it didnt help. Is there any way to fix it other than inspecting incorrect elements for the style description which is causing the problem.

Comment: You can customize bootstrap as said in this article http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2014/6/blog_template_using_bootstrap3_part2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add css rules to the classes after the bootstrap css rules.

Be aware that bootstrap uses `box-sizing: border-box;` for all elements, which might cause your improper alignment.

Under the above `border-box` mode, `width` and `height` includes both border and padding, which are usually don't, be aware of that, or use `box-sizing: content-box;` for your own elements.

So if the reset stylesheet set the `box-sizing` to `content-box`, the origin bootstrap alignment will be destroyed.